# Flutter abiFilters not generating libflutter.so for all architecture

Tags: android, flutter, abi

In my Flutter application I am trying to generate apk that should work on all the devices whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.

For that I have put the following lines in my **build.gradle** file. But it looks like it is not generating the **libflutter.so** for all the architectures.

```
    android {
       compileSdkVersion 27
       defaultConfig {
           appId "com.google.example.64bit"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 28
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

As we can see in the below image the **libflutter.so** is present only in **armeabi-v7a** and all other folder are missing it. This issue crashes my app on startup when I release it on Google Play.

> ```
>   Exceptions
>     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/abc.xyz.idar-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/abc.xyz.idar-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/abc.xyz.idar-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
> ```

[image]

I am using **flutter build apk** command to generate the apk.

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling for this issue for more than a month. Finally flutter has released a so called **PATCH** in manner to support the 64 bit application building support.

To build the application by their architecture use flutter **SDK version 1.7.4 or greater**. Its still in dev channel but things are working as expected. Here is the link to download the [SDK](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)

Now lets come to main code where all magic happens:

**DO NOT INCLUDE ANY ABI FILTERS IN YOUR GRADLE FILE TO GENERATE THE SPLIT APKs**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Now open terminal and use this command on your root directory to generate the Apks

```
\\PATH_TO_YOUR_FLUTTER_SDK_DIR\bin\flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

For example in my case:

```
D:\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter_v1.7.4-dev\flutter\bin\flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

Well it will take pretty long time to generate, but it worth and works lol... here is some output logs for just reference.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     139.7s (!)
Built build\app\outputs\apk\release\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (10.0MB).
Built build\app\outputs\apk\release\app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (10.3MB).
```

Comment: Working good with 1.7.4, thanks for the update man. saved the day

Comment: painting.dart:1657:15: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
it gives me error :(

Comment: Do you have a fix that fixes play store app bundle?

Answer (score 3):

This is a currently known issue in Flutter repository. I hope they are able to fix this soon.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18494.

I found the best work around is to follow this [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18494#issuecomment-454567039).

When you run `flutter build apk`, this work around will remove all resources in 64-bit folders. Thus, the 64-bit device will only use resources in 32-bit folder.

Comment: Do I need to generate and upload two APKs? One for arm64-v8a and other for armeabi-v7a? When I did flutter build apk it generated apk with armeabi-v7a only.

Comment: @Sam, No for now. But Yes from August 2019, Google requires APK to have 64-bit support. So from that time, you need to generate two APKs: 32-bit, and 64-bit, and upload 2 APKs to Google store. You can also generate one AAB (Android app bundle) `flutter build appbundle`, and upload that to Google store. But, I don't know if the later option really works for Flutter.

Comment: thanks for your time and help. My app is not crashing now. Hope they will fix the issue in the near future as I can see it is not assigned to anyone :-)

Comment: some user reported the app is still crashing on their mobile. I think it is 86 bit device. Do you know what can be done?

Comment: @Sam: Did you find the solution. I need to generate x86 architecture app but it keep crashing because of missing libflutter.so

Comment: @MunishThakur I switched to stable channel of flutter and upgrade all my packages. Then it started working.

Comment: @Sam: Which flutter version you are on? I will use that only.

Answer (score 1):

Upgarde/Switch to flutter master channel (if you aren't using it). The issue is resolved by Flutter team. Now, a single command `flutter build apk` will produce the apk compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit architecture.

Comment: I am using Android Studio on Windows machine. How can I upgrade/switch to the master channel. Also this command will produce the single apk that I can upload at once?

Comment: Yes, this command will produce a single APK file. Use command "flutter channel master" to switch. For upgrade, it's "flutter upgrade"

Comment: I switched to master channel and upgrade the flutter. Then I tried the command but it is still not creating the libflutter.so file for other architecture. I can find it only under armeabi-v7a and that is why the app crashes on startup.

Comment: Please run "flutter clean" to clean the build and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your build.gradle like so

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   defaultConfig {
      // Remove ndk.abiFilters from here
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
       }
   }
```

That is what I use to release on Google Play and I haven't got any issue so far.

Comment: When I put the release block inside the android block the gradle build fails when I run flutter build apk.

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method release() for arguments [build_7ydgmn6mc1qqyegyvt3fid2vs$_run_closure2$_closure7@44a36f4c] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: @Sam I updated the answer. Release needs to be nested inside buildTypes

Comment: I tried that but it is still not creating the libflutter.so in any folder except armeabi-v7a.

Comment: That is totally fine. Just one lib folder (armeabi-v7a) which will make the apk compatible with 32 and 64 bit architectures.

Comment: What about x86_64 and x86? will it crash there?

Comment: @Sam I haven't experienced any crashes on my app users. Check out this comment from the Flutter website https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command to build 64-bit apk

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle` inside defaultConfig add this:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
}
```

Run `flutter build apk --release`

Send apk file to Play store.